# Non-classicality of coherent state and squeezed states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, statistical-mechanics, quantum-optics, coherent-states

Recently I have started studying about the coherent state and squeezed states of light. But I have a question about why do we call these states non classical? What are the things that deny their classical behaviour?

Comment: One easy way to see that they are non-classical is that they are expressed with quantum wavefunctions. If they are classical, then they should only be expressible as classical mixtures on the density operator. So, as much as coherent states are the most classical of quantum states, they are still quantum and not classical.

Answer (score 1):

Classical and non-classical states differ by their [photon statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_statistics).

The state of light
(for example, for a mode in an electromagnetic cavity) is always characterized by a quantum-mechanical density matrix. This density matrix can be represented
as one of the quasi-probability distributions, such as [Glauber-Sudarshan P representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glauber%E2%80%93Sudarshan_P_representation) or
[Wigner function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution). In a manner quite similar to the classical probability theory,
quasi-probability distributions allow to find photon statistics, i.e. the probabilities to detect $k$ photons in a given time interval,
correlation functions, etc.

For some states, the quasi-probability distributions behave just like usual probability distributions. In this case, photon statistics can be well described
by a purely classical model of a random field amplitude obeying some probability distribution. Because of that, such states are called classical.
For example, this holds for the coherent state and thermal state.

On the contrary, for non-classical states, for example, squeezed states and Fock states, there exists no classical field probability distribution which reproduces their photon statistics.

Answer (score 0):

Quantum physics says two things: 1) every matter is wave, 2) every wave has the smallest unit/quantum when measured by its energy, mass etc.

Coherent and squeezed lights do not differ in most of the wave characteristics -- frequency, wave function. But they differ when you measure them:

- When measuring the photon numbers received per second, coherent light shows difference from squeezed light
- When measuring the electric vs. the magnetic fields, you find differences.